# Intermittent fatal error (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

> This error is intermittent. Sometimes the app works fine and sometimes it does not.

I have a view controller getNamesViewController which has an alamofire request, it also has a scroll view that loads extra nibs to allow the user to scroll left or right through the content

The results from alamofire are passed to each of the views like so:

```
self.vc0.a = self.a
```

where vc0 has been declared as the xib:

```
let vc0 = displayRegionsViewController(nibName: "displayRegionsViewController", bundle: nil)
```

The alamofire that gets the results and passes them to the variables is:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: ["api_key": api])
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    self.a = json["totalCountName"].stringValue
                    self.b = json["namesRegion"].stringValue
                    
                        
                        self.vc0.a = self.a
                        self.vc0.b = self.b
                       
                    }
                    
            }
            case .Failure(let error):
            print(error)
            }
            
    }
```

> This data gets values from the JSON (The JSON returns 0 if there are no results)

On the nib file, The variables are initialized like so:

```
var a:Int? = 0
var b:Int? = 0

var c:Float? = 00.0
var d:Float? = 00.0
```

Then in the view did load, I have this code:

```
    func percentageSum (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> String {
        let result = round((Double(lhs) / Double(rhs)) * 100)
        return String(result) + "%"
    }
    
    func percentageSumFloat (lhs: Float, rhs: Float) -> Float {
        
        let floatreturn = Float((lhs / rhs) * 100)
        print(floatreturn)
        return floatreturn
    }
    
    //Convert passed value to int
    a = Int(a)
    b = Int(b)

    
    
    if (a != 0) && (b != 0) {
        self.displayViewsTotal.text = percentageSum(self.a!,rhs: self.b!)
        campaignOpensTotalChart.updateProgressCircle(percentageSumFloat(c!,rhs: d!))
        campaignOpensTotalChart.changeLineWidth(CGFloat(20))
        SwiftSpinner.hide()
    }else {
        SwiftSpinner.show("Unexpected Error, Try again").addTapHandler({
            
            SwiftSpinner.hide({
                self.initRun()
            })
            }, subtitle: "Tap to try again..")
    }
```

Now, as I said sometimes (More than not) This works, but every now and then (more on actual device) I get the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

At Xcode highlights this line:

```
self.displayViewsTotal.text = percentageSum(self.a!,rhs: self.b!)
```

Confession:

I am a noob at this, trying to get straight into development by building an app.

This is what I want:

- Use alamofire to connect to the JSON API and get the results (Which are String Form)
- Once alamofire is complete, pass those new values to variables declared in the nib files which are loaded in the scroll view.

or, if the way I am doing it so far is acceptable, I would simply like a way to make this code:

```
self.displayViewsTotal.text = percentageSum(self.a!,rhs: self.b!)
        campaignOpensTotalChart.updateProgressCircle(percentageSumFloat(c!,rhs: d!))
        campaignOpensTotalChart.changeLineWidth(CGFloat(20))
```

not throw the error above.

Please help me guys, I am bashing my head against the wall here.

## Edit: Thoughts

- I think it might be wither something to do with the view getting loaded before alamofire has loaded the data, however I used:

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { }

which I believe fixes that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not sure your optionals are not nil, don't force wrap them like `self.displayViewsTotal.text = percentageSum(self.a!,rhs: self.b!)`

Just rewrite your code and check your optionals are not nil before using.

```
func percentageSum (lhs: Int?, rhs: Int?) throws -> String {
    guard let lhs = lhs else{
        return "lhs is nil"
    }
    guard let rhs = rhs else{
        return "rhs is nil"
    }
    let result = round((Double(lhs) / Double(rhs)) * 100)
    return String(result) + "%"
}

self.displayViewsTotal.text = percentageSum(self.a,rhs: self.b)
```